# Reading text-file in res/raw, very slow. Using BufferedReader

Tags: java, android

The size of the text-file is 560 kilobytes and has about 24500 rows. Each row is added to a list. Maybe my phone is to old and slow? Phone-model: Samsung GT-S5570 with Android 2.3.4.
It takes about 30 seconds or more to read it and I'm pretty sure that my algorithms outside the Reader-class is not the problem. Anyone else who has encountered a similar problem or has an idea of what the problem could be?

```
        public class Reader {  

        public List<String> read(String file) {  
        Context ctx = ApplicationContextProvider.getContext();  
        List<String> entries = new ArrayList<String>();  

        //Get res/raw text-file id.  
        int resId = ctx.getResources().getIdentifier(file,"raw", ctx.getPackageName());  
        InputStream inputStream = ctx.getResources().openRawResource(resId);  

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream), 8192);  

        try {  
             String test;  
             while (true) {  
                 test = reader.readLine();  

                 if (test == null)  
                     break;  
                 entries.add(test);  
            }  
            inputStream.close();  
            reader.close();  
        } catch (IOException e) {  
            e.printStackTrace();  
        }  

        return entries;  
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The device you describe is a very old and slow device. You should take care to speedup the reading process as much as possible by:

- Initializing the ArrayList to be about the size of expected entries so it doesn't resize itself several times during addition of entries. This involves a lot of operations several times while the array grows as it has to copy all its previous elements again when growing.
- Read the whole file at once and then parse the result.

It is also a good idea to measure how much time each part takes - reading the file and inserting the 24500 strings into the ArrayList. Bad performance may come from the least expected direction.

Please try the following approach and share the results (if possible with time measurements):

```
private char[] readWholeFile(String file) {
    Context ctx = ApplicationContextProvider.getContext();
    int resId = ctx.getResources().getIdentifier(file, "raw", ctx.getPackageName());
    InputStream inputStream = ctx.getResources().openRawResource(resId);

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream), 8192);
    try {
        int length = inputStream.available();
        char[] contents = new char[length];
        reader.read(contents, 0, length);
        return contents;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } finally {
        try {
            if (reader != null) reader.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
}


public List<String> readEntries() {
    final int EXPECTED_ELEMENTS = 24500;

    char[] contents = readWholeFile("somefile");
    if (contents == null) {
        return new ArrayList<String>();
    }
    List<String> entries = new ArrayList<String>(EXPECTED_ELEMENTS);
    String test;
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new CharArrayReader(contents));
    try {
        while ((test = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            entries.add(test);
        }
        return entries;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return new ArrayList<String>();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (reader != null) reader.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For some reason it takes less time if I don't set the array to the fixed size 24500. Without the fixed size: 35910484987 nanosec. And with fixed size: 36759156654 nanosec. Then I tried your methods: The readWholeFile-method took 281223333 nanosec and the readEntries took 4585771666 nanosec. So your solution is much faster except for the fixed-size-array(!?). It causes an array out of index problem in another class but that's a whole different mystery.:) Thanks for your help.

Comment: Actually constructing ArrayList(INITIAL_CAPACITY) doesn't create a fixed array, but sets its initial capacity. It can grow past this capacity later. May be your are getting IndexOutOfBoundsException in this other class, because you try to add elements not by using method add(Object obj), but method add(int index, Object obj). In this case when you supply an index that's out of the current array bounds, such problem might arise. Or may be you try to read from the array by using nonexistent (too large) index? This problem might be masked otherwise. Please inspect any code dealing with the array.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Going from 35 seconds to 4.8 seconds seems a good speedup. ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you use IOUtils from apache "commons-io" it's even easier.

```
InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.yourNewTextFile);
String s = IOUtils.toString(is);
IOUtils.closeQuietly(is); // don't forget to close your streams
```

you can download them from 
http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/
or
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io